# Python: Not detecting certain cells of table in a word document

Tags: python, docx

```py
import sys 
import re 
import os 
import docx
from docx import Document
f_name = "./List.docx"
try:
    wordDoc = Document(f_name)
except IOError:
    print ("\n*** %s : Word Document NOT found.\n"%(f_name))
tables= wordDoc.tables
for t in range(0,9,1):
    print (tables[1].rows[t].cells[0].text)
```

[image: please click this to see the table from the word document]

Print statement result is as follows

```
item
ham
glass
ring
keys
75
1
Juice
coffee
```

As you can see, it has not detected certain cell[0] elements. Instead cell[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAOq0.png) or cell[2] are printed for row 5,7 ..row 6 and 8 are skipped. I am using python 3.7.4 and my word document version is Microsoft word 2013 (15.0.5197.1000) MSO (15.0.5172.1000) 32-bit. Please let me know the fix.

Comment: Table across pages might be the reason. What happens if the table is in one page?

Comment: the issue is there even if table is in one page :-( I have tried that way

Comment: could anyone help me with this issue ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Width of Description col was the problem. Setting right side of all cells the same worked.